# Why is there no std::string constructor for reference to array?

Tags: c++

String literals are array objects:

```c
typeid("hello").name()   // char [6]
```

This seems convenient because the size of the string literal (=array) is known at compile time. So why is there no constructor to `std::string` that takes a reference to an array?

```c
// this would be great
template <int N>
std::string(const char (& array)[N]);
```

Instead there are constructors that take `const char * s`, `const char * s, size_t n` or two `InputIterator`s (eg. `const char * begin, const char * end`). All of these have drawbacks; the array is implicitly converted to a pointer and the size information is lost, so various methods are used to get it back. Working, but increasingly crazy examples:

```c
// std::string(const char * s) version:
std::string s1("hello");                      // calls std::strlen(s) internally

// std::string(const char * s, size_t n) version:
std::string s2("hello", 5);                   // programmer does std::strlen(s) mentally
std::string s3("hello", sizeof("hello"));     // have to repeat string literal

// macro helper to avoid repeating string literal (ugly and dangerous)
#define STRLIT(x) std::string(x, sizeof(x));  // could be a function I guess
std::string s4 = STRLIT("hello");             // not much improvement (and macros are evil)

// std::string(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end) version:
char tmp[] = "hello";                         // copy array
std::string s5(&tmp[0], &tmp[sizeof(tmp)]);   // so you can reference it twice

// or trust the compiler to return the same address for both literals
std::string s6(&"hello"[0], &"hello"[sizeof("hello")]);   // totally crazy
```

Comment: You can always write your own `make_string` function which does this.

Comment: fyi the `sizeof` catches the null byte and returns 6.

Comment: `STRLIT` can be an inline function rather than a macro.  `tmeplate<int len> std::string strlit(const char(&str)[len]) {return std::string(str,len);}` (this is also what Pubby suggests)

Comment: String literals are array *objects*, not types.

Comment: A good compiler will have a constant-time version of `strlen` for literal strings.

Comment: Challenge: Try to write a program, where this speed difference is noticeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key question when considering whether there should be a constructor taking a `char const (&)[N]` (for some statically determined `N`) is what the content of the resulting `std::string` should be. It might be obvious to some what it should be but I don't think it is. Consider this `std::string("abc\0def")`:

1. It could be a string with 8 elements, including the two null bytes.
2. It could be a string with 7 elements, excluding the second null bytes.
3. It could be a string with 3 elements, excluding everything starting at the first null byte.

If you use

```
std::cout << "string='" << "abc\0def" << "'\n";
```

you get the third option. It seems, this is the only sane alternative...

Comment: I think the answer's buried in Dietmar's answer:  Because an array of character could validly contain the string terminator sequence.  Guarding against that case will swallow up the time saved using the array size.

Comment: You're right, there doesn't seem to be any way of making this do "the right thing" (whatever that means in each situation). I guess if you want a specific behavior you could always write your own make_string function for that case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Such a templated constructor would be separately instantiated for each value of `N`. This could result in unnecessary code bloat.

The bloat is avoidable, but let's combine this thought with an answer from the ever-quotable [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing):

> The answer to "Why doesn't this feature exist?" is usually "By default features don't exist. Somebody has to implement them."

Comment: nonsense, zero construct all members, then call `assign(ptr, size)`, after inlining, there's no bloat for each `N`

Comment: To expand on what  @Mooing Duck says, with C++11, all it would have to do is delegate to the `string(ptr, size)` constructor.  The delegation would almost certainly get inlined.  No bloat.

Comment: Well, what I suggested is slightly less likely to be inlined, but happens to also work in C++03

Answer (score 1):

Because there is a generic constructor that uses iterators:

```
std::string s7(std::begin(container), std::end(container));
```

Note: assumes c++11 for std::begin/std::end but you can quickly write something similar really easyily.